# How to search for text string in executable output with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python script to auto update a program for me. When I run program.exe --help, it gives a long output and inside the output is a string with value of `"Version: X.X.X"` How can I make a script that runs the command and isolates the version number from the executable's output?

I should have mentioned that I tried the following:

```
import re 
import subprocess

regex = r'Version: ([\d\.]+)'

match = re.search(regex, subprocess.run(["program.exe", "--help"])) 

print((match.group(0)))
```

and got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 6, in <module>
    match = re.search(regex, subprocess.run(["program.exe", "--help"]))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with in particular?  What have you tried already?  What went wrong?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at the `subprocess` and `re` modules.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
re.search(r'Version: ([\d\.]+)', subprocess.check_output(['program.exe', '--help']).decode()).group(1)
```

Comment: When I run this, it only prints the second line of the program's output and not the version number. (Prints "Build Date: Jun 27 2019", instead of "1.7.7")

Comment: That's strange, what is the output you get with `check_output`? I've tried with a test string and the regex seems to work: ```>>> test="foo\nBuild Date: Jun 27 2019\nVersion: 1.7.7\nbar\n"
>>> re.search(r'Version: ([\d\.]+)', foo).group(1)
'1.7.7'
```

Comment: Oh crap, I just realized that i put the version number instead of the build date. The build date's the one I need. With `check_output` I get, `RetroArch: Frontend for libretro -- v1.7.7`. With `run` I get, `===================================================================
RetroArch: Frontend for libretro -- v1.7.7 -- 550ea0f143 --
Compiler: MinGW (7.3.0) 64-bitBuilt: Jun 27 2019
===================================================================`

Comment: Then just use `'Built: ([\w\s]+)'` instead of `'Version: ([\d\.]+)' ` as pattern in `re.search`

Comment: I tried that and it still outputs `RetroArch: Frontend for libretro -- v1.7.7`